# pointer to array and then getting full array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

**EDIT (Remake):** Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
char* someArray = new char[someIntVariable];
```

And then loop over the array and use a custom function to get the contents of the other array (that's where the problem lies):

```
char* temp = someFunc(someArray, someIntVariable); //someFunc is a char* returning function
for(int i = 0; i < someIntVariable; i++){
    someArray[i] = temp[i] //temp[i] is where the problem lies. It returns something like: /213
}
```

Text version: I'm trying to get a pointer to a char array to return all of the arrays contents (only using one single pointer) and loop over a previously created array and fill it's spaces or somehow assign it one single assignment.

Hope this is comprehensible.

"someFunc":

```
char* convertCharArr(char* _inputArr, int arrSize){
    char *inputArr = new char[arrSize];
    std::memmove(inputArr, _inputArr, sizeof(*inputArr));
    static char *resizedUsrInptAns = new char[arrSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(inputArr)/sizeof(inputArr[0]); i++){
        if(i == arrSize + 1){
            break;
        }
        resizedUsrInptAns[i] = inputArr[i];
    }
    return resizedUsrInptAns;
}
```

Comment: `ptr2` does *not* point to `ptr1`. They both point to the same `char`. If you want to point to `ptr1`, you need to write `char** ptr2 = &ptr1;`

Comment: Your requirements are not at all clear. The obvious answer (or one of them) would be `char arr2[5]; for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) arr2[i] = ptr2[i];` -- It fulfills all the requirements you listed, but I would assume you could have figured that solution out for yourself.

Comment: You want to copy an array? See `strcpy`. Still not clear.

Comment: @DonReba In some way, yes I want to copy it. (I guess I can't write in english very well if it's still not clear xP). I want to copy the FULL array instead of just the pointer which only points to the first element. (i hope it's clear now)

Comment: @Code0 It's always better to show a [short concise code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than writing incomprehensible prose.

Comment: Your best option would be to not use C arrays in C++. They are nearly always a wrong choice if you need an array, because they are not the same kind of arrays higher level languages (including C++) have.

Comment: I do fully understand that. However, since I've just started out programming in c++/c, I'd like to know how things like this exactly work and be able to perform such a thing as asked in the question. @hyde

Answer (score 1):

`ptr2` and `ptr1` are equivalent, so I am going to ignore `ptr2` for my answer.

If you want to clone a char array of unknown size, you have to use dynamic memory allocation:

```
char * p = malloc(strlen(ptr1) + 1);
strcpy(p, ptr1);
// ...
free(p);
```

Comment: Or simply use [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is that a standard function?

Comment: It is POSIX2008 which is a standard. It is indeed probably not C++11 or C99 which are other standards. The nice thing with standards is that you can choose which one you want to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a pointer to an array, thats impossible in c. You can only do the opposite, assigning an array to a pointer.

You will have to create a new array(with dynamic allocation) and copy the data into that array.

**Example**

```
char* pChar = GetArrayPointer();

char* pNewArrayPointer = (char*)malloc(strlen(pChar) + 1);

strcpy(pNewArrayPointer, pChar);
```

**Edit**

1) You don't have to copy `_inputArr` because you don't write data to it in `converCharArr()`.

2) Why are you using `sizeof(inputArr)/sizeof(inputArr[0])`, it doesn't works, because inputArr is a pointer(well, there are some differences between pointers and arrays :)). You should use `arrSize`.

Array and pointer differences : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-5/

Comment: Edited my original question. Sorry about that. I described it incorrectly.

Comment: After doing this, as far as I know, I end up with a pointer to the FIRST element of an array. However, I'd like to end up with an array containing the stuff of the original array. Only by using the pointer to the first element.

Comment: A pointer to the first element of an array or the array itself are equivalent in c

Comment: Then why does it return something like "/213" when I try somePtrToArr[3]? I tried de-referecing but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show what someFunc does?

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 0):

In your example both prt1 as well as ptr2 are pointing to same char. And you can get same effects for ptr1/ptr2 using cout what you get for arr1.

So, below all will print same thing:-

```
cout << arr1;
cout << ptr1;
cout << ptr2;
```

If you want to create new array using ptr2 with same contents as of arr1, then

```
ptr2 = malloc(strlen(ptr1) + 1);
strcpy(ptr2, ptr1);
```

Comment: I edit my post now. I didn't really tell you what I wanted correctly. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

May this would help
link: http://ideone.com/Nwqd22

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* fun(){
    char * returnValue = "String";

    return returnValue;
}

int main() {

    char * firstVariable;
    firstVariable = fun();
    cout << firstVariable;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. I'm however explicitly looking for char arrays.

Comment: post some code example?

Comment: Done hopefully it's comprehensible